# Kobold2d 2.0.4 warnings

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

Ever since I updated to Kobold2d 2.0.4 I keep getting these warnings in the console.

```
2012-09-26 16:36:00.455 KTireHoops-iOS[14583:c07] ===> WARNING: property setter 'setAutorotationType:' not defined in target: <KKStartupConfig: 0x1047efe0> <===
2012-09-26 16:36:00.455 KTireHoops-iOS[14583:c07] ===> WARNING: property setter 'setDeviceOrientation:' not defined in target: <KKStartupConfig: 0x1047efe0> <===
2012-09-26 16:36:00.456 KTireHoops-iOS[14583:c07] ===> WARNING: property setter 'setShouldAutorotateToLandscapeOrientations:' not defined in target: <KKStartupConfig: 0x1047efe0> <===
2012-09-26 16:36:00.456 KTireHoops-iOS[14583:c07] ===> WARNING: property setter 'setAllowAutorotateOnFirstAndSecondGenerationDevices:' not defined in target: <KKStartupConfig: 0x1047efe0> <===
2012-09-26 16:36:00.456 KTireHoops-iOS[14583:c07] ===> WARNING: property setter 'setShouldAutorotateToPortraitOrientations:' not defined in target: <KKStartupConfig: 0x1047efe0> <===
2012-09-26 16:36:00.457 KTireHoops-iOS[14583:c07] ===> WARNING: property setter 'setDirectorTypeFallback:' not defined in target: <KKStartupConfig: 0x1047efe0> <===
2012-09-26 16:36:00.547 KTireHoops-iOS[14583:c07] ===> WARNING: property setter 'setWindowFrame:' not defined in target: <KKStartupConfig: 0x1047efe0> <===
2012-09-26 16:36:00.548 KTireHoops-iOS[14583:c07] ===> WARNING: property setter 'setDirectorType:' not defined in target: <KKStartupConfig: 0x1047efe0> <===
```

Are these something that I need to fix or can I ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are deprecated properties in config.lua when you upgrade from Kobold2D v1.x to v2.x. You can ignore them, or simply remove the corresponding entries from config.lua.